# Find and Replace in wordpress postings

Tags: text-processing, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog with 93 posts on it, in which I want to replace `[bash]` with `<pre>` but how do I do it please? I need to go through all the posts changing `[bash]` to `<pre>` in each one, but the `[bash]` doesn't appear in every posting but it is in quite a few, too many to do it by hand with one post after another, I'd rather do it in batches if possible.

I believe the posts are stored in a MySQL database, but I can't remember why I believe so!

Comment: Are the blog posts stored in files or in a database? If a db, which database?

Comment: I believe its a mysql database, but I cant remember why I believe so!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're running WP on top of a MySQL database, and that your table prefix is `wp_`, then you'll want to run a query like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(REPLACE(post_content, '[bash]', '<pre>'), '[/bash]', '</pre>')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[bash]%'
```

Take a backup first, just in case!

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u username -p your_wp_database_name > backup.sql
```

Comment: Sammitch - This is on a hosted space site run by 1and1, with the database name beginning db***** . Does this still apply to your previous answer please?

Comment: The best solution I found was to use a wordpress plugin called 'Search & Replace' which amended the database, and worked very well making my changes.